# Baking powder on Pesach

Tags: halacha, food, passover, cooking-bishul, chametz-leaven

I know intellectually that chemical leavening agents are allowed during Pesach. Kosher baking powder (free from kitinyot) is widely available. Still, I can't help feeling that it's *cheating* to use these products. Are there modern rabbinic authorities that are opposed to their use? If so, on what grounds?

Comment: Note that their use would be restricted to recipes calling for other kosher-for-Passover ingredients, and (at least in the vast majority of cases) not flour. One could not, e.g., make a cake with baking powder, despite its not being yeast, if flour and water were also ingredients. As always, for practical _halacha_, [CYLOR](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/594) rather than relying on what you read on this site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.nytimes.com/2006/04/05/dining/05leav.html?pagewanted=all

> But rabbis in even some of the most Orthodox associations say chometz
>   does not refer to all leavening.
>
> "There is nothing wrong about a raised product at Passover per se,"
>   said Rabbi Moshe Elefant, executive rabbinic coordinator and chief
>   operating officer of the Orthodox Union's kosher division, the oldest
>   and most widely accepted certifier of kosher foods.
>
> Lise Stern, author of "How to Keep Kosher" (Morrow, 2004), said:
>   "Chometz, which means sharp or sour, denotes bread that has a sourness
>   to it caused by fermentation, occurring when liquid is added to any of
>   the five grains mentioned in the Torah. This refers to yeast, not
>   baking powder or baking soda."
>
> Rabbi Soloveichik said: "They're just minerals. What do we care about
>   minerals?"

Comment: I did see this article, but the wording "... in even *some* of the most Orthodox associations ..." left me wondering whether there might be *others* that disagreed. Thanks for your answer -- if no one has come up with an objection yet then I feel better!

Comment: What is "most Orthodox"? Do they mean "most orthodox"?